# Print a symbol for product (∏) by using SymPy package

Tags: python, sympy

[image]

I would like to know how to print the symbols in this picture by using SymPy package in Python.

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html?highlight=product#sympy.concrete.products.product

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic products are created with `Product(expr, (index, low, high))` where `high` is *inclusive* unlike in much of Python code. For example:

```
P00 = IndexedBase("P^{00}")
P02 = IndexedBase("P^{02}")
i = Idx("i")
t = symbols("t")
expr = Product(P00[i]*P02[t], (i, 1, t-1))
print(expr)
```

which prints (assuming LaTeX support) as

[image: product]

The placement of indices is suboptimal; the issue is that the superscripts are hardcoded into symbol names instead of being actual raised indices. But I don't see a way to tell SymPy to print certain indices as superscripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My boss asked me to print it using Sympy. Anyway, thank you.