# sympy Sequence : how to use product?

Tags: sympy

[Print a symbol for product (∏) by using SymPy package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866286/print-a-symbol-for-product-%e2%88%8f-by-using-sympy-package)

What am I doing wrong with the macro?

```
from sympy import *
i = Idx("i")
a = IndexedBase("a")
n = symbols("n")
f=Product(a[i], (i,2,n) )
print(f)
g=Product(a[i], (i,1,n-1) )
print(g)
print(simplify(f/g))
# Product(a[i], (i, 2, n))
# Product(a[i], (i, 1, n - 1))
# Product(a[i], (i, 2, n))/Product(a[i], (i, 1, n - 1))

# I want
# a(n)    a(n-1)
# a(n-1)  a(n-2)
#      .
#      .
#      .  a(2) 
# a(2)    a(1)
# ---->
# a(n)/a(1)
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong - simplify does not support this kind of simplification.
Why not write something yourself?